# other names of Hashem (instead of Ado..) in davenning and brachos?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, blessing, shemos-sacred-names

IS there halachic basis for using other names of Hashem (instead of Ado..) in davenning and brachos, if one chooses?

Comment: Could you please be more specific with this question? Are you thinking about some names in particular? What part of davening? Why might someone choose to do this?

Comment: @Daniel: I have heard a (conservative) woman use יה instead of אדני to avoid using a masculine word. (Oh, and don't print this page!)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is plenty. The Shulchan Aruch rules (OC 187:1) that if one says רחמנא (the merciful One) as God's name in bentching he has fulfilled his obligation. Later, in OC 214 when discussing the requirement to have God's name in a blessing, the Mishna Berura notes that any of God's 7 names which cannot be erased (see [Rambam Yesodei haTorah 6:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1106.htm#2)) are certainly no worse than רחמנא and would work as well. All this is of course to some extent *[bedieved](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/702/759)* as we try not to adjust the language of our fixed prayers unnecessarily.

Comment: I can't imagine this situation ever coming up bedieved.

Comment: @Daniel In general, I've learned never to say that :) For this case, perhaps it might come up if someone skips Adonay but says Eloheinu. It's also relevant when saying prayer/blessings in a language other than Hebrew.

Comment: @Daniel The Leshem actually brings a segula in his Shearim to say the Amidah with Ehy-eh in place of Ado-nai.  So... I can see it being done under certain circumstances.

Comment: @DoubleAA, fair point. Probably nobody would accidentally say "Rachmana", though.

Comment: @RabbiMichaelTzadok, that's not bedieved then.

Comment: @DoubleAA btw, what names of God can't be erased in languages other than Hebrew?

Comment: @Daniel Depends who you ask :) Note that רחמנא isn't one so the Mishna Berura's mentioning the names which can't be erased is a very minimalist position. There is what to be said about using other names in Brachot as well.