# Saying Hashem instead of Adonoy in a bracha

Tags: blessing, shemos-sacred-names

[This question's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27964/other-names-of-hashem-instead-of-ado-in-davenning-and-brachos/27968#27968) cites a section from the Shulchan Aruch that says you are yotzei if you say "Rachamana" instead of "Adonoy" in a bracha.

What about if you say "Hashem" instead of "Adonoy" or "Elokim" instead of "Elohim"? Have you still fulfilled your obligation?

Comment: Rachmana ("the merciful [one]") is a name of God, while Hashem ("the name") is not (God Himself is not a name (nor is He an Adoshem [?]), but He is merciful). I'm not sure I see why you think they'd be similar.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47714 (cc @DoubleAA)